# Connect to kubernetes with AWS Lambda function

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, aws-lambda, amazon-eks

I am trying to create a lambda function for an Alexa skill that will connect to an EKS cluster. I am creating the cluster using with Terraform and hosting it on AWS. I am not sure if I am correctly exporting my function correctly and would appreciate some feedback.

```
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk')
const Client = require('kubernetes-client').Client

const connect = require("./connect");

const LaunchRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === "LaunchRequest";
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    console.log("Launch Request Handler Called");

    let speechText =
      "KubeVoice Test";
    let repromptText =
      "I did not receive any input. You can say, Connect to Cluster.";

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(repromptText)
      .getResponse();
  }
};

//Handler for connecting
const KubernetesConnect = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        
        return (
            handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === "IntentRequest" && 
            handlerInput.request.intent.name === "Connect"
        );
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        let connectToCluster = connect.connect();
        let speechText = "connected to cluster";
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(speechText).getResponse();
    }
};

const UnhandledHandler = {
    canHandle() {
        return true;
    },
    handle(handlerInput, error) {
        console.log(`Error Handler : ${error.message}`);
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(
            "Sorry, I am unable to process your request, ask me to connect"
            ).getResponse();
    }
};



exports.handler = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom().
    addRequestHandlers(
        LaunchRequestHandler,
        KubernetesConnect,
    )
    .addErrorHandlers(UnhandledHandler)
    .lambda();
```

And the code for connecting to the eks cluster is taken from the Godaddy Kubernetes client example

```
const Client = require('kubernetes-client').Client

async function connect() {
    try {
        const client = new Client({
            config: {
                url: process.env.K8S_CLUSTER_HOST,
                auth: {
                    provider: {
                        type: 'cmd',
                        config: {
                            'cmd-path': 'aws-iam-authenticator',
                            'cmd-args': 'token -i' + process.env.K8S_AUTH_TOKEN,
                            'cmd-env': {
                                AWS_PROFILE: process.env.AWS_PROFILE
                            },
                            'token-key': 'status.token'
                        }
                    }
                },
                insecureSkipTlsVerify: true
            },
            version: process.env.K8S_CLUSTER_VERSION
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error('Error: ', err);
    }
}

module.exports.connect = connect;
```

This is the error I am getting

```
2021-04-10T13:45:14.982Z    c1c8c985-5eb0-43dd-a041-5a077ca12b6c    INFO    Error Handler : Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

was missing `.requestEnvelope` on the line for the connect intent. The code functions now, just need to sort IAM roles for the cluster!